# SequelizeJS - include tables with hasMany + joinTableName. The cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Here are my models:
Users
Groups
Comments

```
Users.hasMany(Groups, {foreignKey: 'userID', joinTableName: 'user_has_groups'});
Comments.hasMany(Users, {foreignKey: 'groupID', joinTableName: 'user_has_groups'});

Users.hasMany(Comments);
Comments.belongsTo(Users);
```

So basically, my **users** and my **groups** are in an n:m table (user_has_groups) where I link the userID and the groupID. A user can have many groups, and a group can have many users.
The second part is linking my **users** to their **comments**. A user can have many comments, and a comment belongs to a user.

Now, if I want to display the groups of each user, I would do:

```
Users.findAll({ include : [ Groups ] }).success( function(result) {     
    res.json(result);
});
```

I will send me a result like that, as intended:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ken",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Administrators"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Contributors"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Barbie",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Contributors"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Readers"
    }]
}
```

The same goes if I just include my Comments:

```
Users.findAll({ include : [ Comments ] }).success( function(result) {       
    res.json(result);
});
```

I don't display here but trust me, the results are fine.
Now, if I want to include both groups and comments, sequelize doesn't know how to handle the cartesian product. It will display:

```
Users.findAll({ include : [ Groups, Comments ] }).success( function(result) {       
    res.json(result);
});


{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ken",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Administrators"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Contributors"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Administrators"
    }],
    "comments":[{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "First! lol"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Barbie",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Contributors"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Readers"
    },{
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Contributors"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Readers"
    }],
    "comments":[{
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Hey Ken!"
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Why don't you answer!?"
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Why don't you answer!?"
    }]
}
```

So... I was just wondering if someone else has already faced this situation, or what would you do?
I really would like to get both groups and comments from a user in the same result.
If I can't via sequelize [eager loading](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-eager-loading), I will perform [raw queries](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#usage-raw-queries)...

Thanks!

---

### WORK AROUND

This seems to do the trick (+ check the link in the choosen answer):

```
Users.find(id).success(function(user){
    Groups.findAll({ where:{ userID:user.id }}).success(function(groups){
        Comments.findAll({ where:{ userID:user.id }}).success(function(comments){      
            res.json({
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                groups: groups,
                comments: comments,
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading of nested associations is underway but not yet complete. You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/388

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't have the keyword "nested associations". I edited my question to give a temporary solution, taken from the link.

Comment: Glad to help. I hope Sequelize will get Rails-style nested associations soon.